# How to keep all rows of all columns that have NAs

Tags: r

Any idea on how to apply a function on a dataframe using `dplyr` in a way that I keep only rows that have any missing value?

Answer (score 4):

Using @DJack's sample data [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50241533/7028459), we can do this in `dplyr` using `filter_all`. `filter_all` takes an argument quoted in `all_vars` or `any_vars` and applies it to all columns. Here, we keep any row that returns `TRUE` for `is.na` in any column.

```r
m <- matrix(1:25, ncol = 5)
m[c(1, 6, 13, 25)] <- NA
df <- data.frame(m)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter_all(any_vars(is.na(.)))
#>   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
#> 1 NA NA 11 16 21
#> 2  3  8 NA 18 23
#> 3  5 10 15 20 NA
```

Created on 2018-05-08 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: That worked just fine in a very elegant way. Any hints about these other two situations -  Remove all columns with missing values and ,
        Keep only columns with missing values.

Comment: Both are done with `select_if`. In `dplyr`, `filter` verbs allow you to keep rows, `select` verbs allow you to keep columns in various ways.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a (not `dplyr`) solution:

```
df[rowSums(is.na(df)) > 0,]

#  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
#1 NA NA 11 16 21
#3  3  8 NA 18 23
#5  5 10 15 20 NA
```

Or as suggested by MrFlick:

```
df[!complete.cases(df),]
```

#### Sample data

```
m <- matrix(1:25, ncol = 5)
m[c(1,6,13,25)] <- NA
df <- data.frame(m)
df

#  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
#1 NA NA 11 16 21
#2  2  7 12 17 22
#3  3  8 NA 18 23
#4  4  9 14 19 24
#5  5 10 15 20 NA
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to solve this with dplyr, but maybe this helps:

First, I created this df:

```
df <- tribble( ~a ,  ~b, ~c,
               1  , NA ,  0,
               2  ,  0 ,  1,
               3  ,  1 ,  NA,
               4  ,  1 ,  0
             )
```

Then, this will return only rows with NA:

```
df[!complete.cases(df),]
```

See more:
[Subset of rows containing NA (missing) values in a chosen column of a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980622/subset-of-rows-containing-na-missing-values-in-a-chosen-column-of-a-data-frame)

Comment: This good, just trying both approaches. Let you guys know how it goes.

Comment: I was answering at the same time! But this validates your solution, right?!